# HighSlide - плагин JS

Tags: css, javascript

Это плагин для увелечения картинок, но по какой-то причине при увелечении фотка наоборот уменьшается, а в нижнем правом углу появляется кнопка, нажав на которую увеличится так, как надо, так происходит только с большими картинками, как написано в мануале, прописал:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   hs.maxWidth = 4000;
hs.maxHeight = 4000;
</script>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, плагин плохой, я уже понял, но менять не хочу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему сам) В функции, которая определяет размер экрана добавил в ширину и высоту по 5к пикселей - всё стало ещё лучше чем я думал, функция getPageSize вроде, код не кину ,т.к. на другом компе делал)

Answer (score 0):

highslide подстраивает размер картинки под размер вашего экрана, при нажатии на кнопку внизу картинка и должна открываться в полный размер.

Comment: Это я уже понял, мне нужно как-то отключить подгон к экрану...